# Update access application file without changing the data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just finished developing a Microsoft Access database application for a friend and he started entering data already.

He just contacted me that he would like to add additional features to the application (Nothing Major).

He is using his computer (to enter data) at one location and i use a different computer at a different location (to build the application). My Question is, is there a way when i finish updating my (empty) copy of the application to replace it with his copy of the application without effecting the data he entered into the database?

Comment: Assuming he can't/will not update anything other than the data in tables, you can grab his database and import his tables into your latest version (replacing the ones you have).  If you made structure changes, then it gets a little trickier, but still easy to do.

Comment: You will have to be specific about what you're changing. You can just copy most objects (queries/forms/reports/macro's/modules) from one database to another. Table structure changes and relationships are more difficult, but also possible.

Comment: This time its just to add a field in a table that has no relationships to anything just being displayed in a form. But i asked in general what would be the most efficient way of doing it now and in the feature.

Comment: The short story is, we would place VBA code to handle all types of structure changes and execute that code the first time the database was deployed and opened. You could do something similar where you just ship the new database to your friend and have it perform all the steps you would have manually performed. I can provide further detail of how it was done if you are interested. The big question is: How often will you need to do this? Once or twice... do it manually... lots of times? do it via code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is to *split* the database into two: A *backend* with tables only, and a *frontend* with all forms, reports, etc.

There is a wizard that will do 99% of this for you.

When done, you can update the frontend at any time and relink the tables from the backend.

Comment: Where do i find that wizard?

Comment: This really shouldn't cause you trouble ... anyway, hint, menu Database Tools.